# Wx.Media running in Windows but error in Linux

Tags: python, linux, wxpython

First time i create video player with Wx.Media in windows, its fine. The code is working. When i try to running in Linux. Wx.Media doesn't run.

The give me information like this.

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/media.py", line 96, 
in __init__ _media.MediaCtrl_swiginit(self,_media.new_MediaCtrl(*args, **kwargs))
 NotImplementedError
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code example that exhibits the issue?

Comment: The problem from here. Mr @PaulRooney

'self.player = wx.media.MediaCtrl(pan2, pos=(80, 55), size=(800, 600),  style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)'

Comment: IIRC it is only implemented on Windows and Mac.

Comment: For linux, i must use what ? @Werner

Comment: @def_ddd, sorry no idea.